# OneDrive Rest API unable to hit proper endpoint to list all child folders under Documents

Tags: rest, onedrive

I am coding against the OneDrive REST API and am hitting the `https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/root/children` endpoint. I can clearly see that the returned JSON shows there are three `childCount` for the `folder` for Documents.

I am trying to figure out how to structure my endpoint to show the child folders under Document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Query for the children of `Documents` by name
2. Query for the children of `Documents` by id

For the former:

> https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/root:/Documents:/children

For the latter:

> https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/items/<id-of-document>/children

To limit the returned children to just folders you can add a filter:

> https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/root:/Documents:/children?filter=folder%20ne%20null